# Function conv_units() not working inside an ifelse() statement

Tags: r, coordinates

I want to convert geographic coordinates in a table. I have some measurement in decimal degrees (`dec_deg`) and some in decimal minutes (`deg_dec_min`). I want to convert those in decimal minutes to decimal degrees. Using the function `conv_unit()` within a `mutate()` and `ifelse()` statement, I get a Warning message and an incorrect value.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(measurements)

data_latlon <- tibble(latitude = c(8.726088, -16.365242, -19.888074, 
                                   '1 40.232', '0 2.308', '2 2.356'),
                      longitude = c(-83.180764, -62.015502, -40.549983, 
                                    '75 54.301', '70 56.693', '72 41.143'), 
                      unit = c('dec_deg', 'dec_deg', 'dec_deg', 
                               'deg_dec_min', 'deg_dec_min','deg_dec_min'))
```

### Case 1: using ifelse()

```
data_latlon %>% 
  mutate(latitude = ifelse(unit=='deg_dec_min', 
                           conv_unit(latitude, from = 'deg_dec_min', to = 'dec_deg'), 
                           latitude))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  latitude         longitude  unit       
  <chr>            <chr>      <chr>      
1 8.726088         -83.180764 dec_deg    
2 -16.365242       -62.015502 dec_deg    
3 -19.888074       -40.549983 dec_deg    
4 2.34133333333333 75 54.301  deg_dec_min
5 2.356            70 56.693  deg_dec_min
6 0                72 41.143  deg_dec_min
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `latitude = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 
2: Problem while computing `latitude = ifelse(...)`.
ℹ data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

### Case 2: doing it separately

```
data_latlon %>% 
  filter(unit=='deg_dec_min') %>% 
  mutate(latitude = ifelse(unit=='deg_dec_min', 
                           conv_unit(latitude, from = 'deg_dec_min', to = 'dec_deg'), 
                           latitude))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  latitude           longitude unit       
  <chr>              <chr>     <chr>      
1 1.67053333333333   75 54.301 deg_dec_min
2 0.0384666666666667 70 56.693 deg_dec_min
3 2.03926666666667   72 41.143 deg_dec_min
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is `measurments::conv_unit` is intended to receive numeric vector. However, some of your values in latitude column is character. This would be an issue if you run the entire column simultaneously.

For example, running `conv_unit` will return warnings and incorrect results:

```
conv_unit(data_latlon$latitude, from = 'deg_dec_min', to = 'dec_deg')

[1] "8.99884203333333"  "-19.9047406666667" "-40.232"          
[4] "2.34133333333333"  "2.356"             "0"                
Warning messages:
1: In as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x_na_free, " "))) * c(3600, 60) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In split.default(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x_na_free, " "))) *  :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

**Solution:**

The easiest solutions are to vectorize the function or use `rowwise()`:

```
conv_unit_vec<-Vectorize(conv_unit)


data_latlon %>% 
  mutate(latitude = ifelse(unit=='deg_dec_min', 
                           conv_unit_vec(latitude, from = 'deg_dec_min', to = 'dec_deg'), 
                           latitude))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  latitude           longitude  unit       
  <chr>              <chr>      <chr>      
1 8.726088           -83.180764 dec_deg    
2 -16.365242         -62.015502 dec_deg    
3 -19.888074         -40.549983 dec_deg    
4 1.67053333333333   75 54.301  deg_dec_min
5 0.0384666666666667 70 56.693  deg_dec_min
6 2.03926666666667   72 41.143  deg_dec_min
```

or:

```
data_latlon %>% 
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(latitude = ifelse(unit=='deg_dec_min', 
                           conv_unit_vec(latitude, from = 'deg_dec_min', to = 'dec_deg'), 
                           latitude)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  latitude           longitude  unit       
  <chr>              <chr>      <chr>      
1 8.726088           -83.180764 dec_deg    
2 -16.365242         -62.015502 dec_deg    
3 -19.888074         -40.549983 dec_deg    
4 1.67053333333333   75 54.301  deg_dec_min
5 0.0384666666666667 70 56.693  deg_dec_min
6 2.03926666666667   72 41.143  deg_dec_min
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @peter861222 ! I think `conv_unit()` can deal with strings else I wouldn't be able to convert a value like `1 40.232` (but they must be numbers). If you see my second case, it works. However, apparently, it cannot deal with mixed char and num. I like the row-wise solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Few things to note here:

- from `?ifelse` : *"`yes` will be evaluated if and only if any element of `test` is true, and analogously for `no`"*; so both `yes` and `no` are fully evaluated here.
- `conv_unit()` does not really check if values in `x` arg make sense.
  Snippet from function source:

```r
    if (from == "deg_dec_min") 
      secs = lapply(split(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x_na_free, 
        " "))) * c(3600, 60), f = rep(1:length(x_na_free), 
        each = 2)), sum)
```

Note how it uses `unlist()`, `c(3600, 60)` and `rep(..., each = 2)`, it relies on an assumption that each element in input vector `x` will be split into exactly 2 numbers, no more no less.
If you take your input vector, `c("8.726088", "-16.365242", "-19.888074", "1 40.232", "0 2.308", "2 2.356")`, split strings by `" "`, and unlist, you will get 9 instead of 12 numbers. This is the reason for the warning and messed up result.

Besides `rowwise()` you could also handle this by e.g. `split()` and `map_at()` to only process rows where `deg_dec_min` is set:

```r
library(measurements)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)

# split to list of tibbles by "unit" column, 
# apply mutate only on "deg_dec_min" part,
# rbind both parts back together
data_latlon %>% 
  split(~ unit) %>% 
  map_at("deg_dec_min", 
         \(x) x %>% mutate(across(ends_with("itude"),
                                  \(coord_col) conv_unit(coord_col, 
                                                         from = 'deg_dec_min', 
                                                         to = 'dec_deg')))) %>% 
  list_rbind()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   latitude           longitude        unit       
#>   <chr>              <chr>            <chr>      
#> 1 8.726088           -83.180764       dec_deg    
#> 2 -16.365242         -62.015502       dec_deg    
#> 3 -19.888074         -40.549983       dec_deg    
#> 4 1.67053333333333   75.9050166666667 deg_dec_min
#> 5 0.0384666666666667 70.9448833333333 deg_dec_min
#> 6 2.03926666666667   72.6857166666667 deg_dec_min
```

Input:

```r
data_latlon <- tibble(latitude = c(8.726088, -16.365242, -19.888074, 
                                   '1 40.232', '0 2.308', '2 2.356'),
                      longitude = c(-83.180764, -62.015502, -40.549983, 
                                    '75 54.301', '70 56.693', '72 41.143'), 
                      unit = c('dec_deg', 'dec_deg', 'dec_deg', 
                               'deg_dec_min', 'deg_dec_min','deg_dec_min'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the details @margusl! Now I understand why it's messing it up :)